# Excel found unreadable content in *.xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on generating an excel template from code. When I run the piece to create my WorkBook, I get no errors in code, however when I go to open the Excel document, I get an error indicating that the file is unreadable. I am able to click to open it anyway, and I get the following message

> Removed Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

Any idea what might be wrong in my code please?

```
public void CreatePackage()
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(FilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        CreateParts(package);
    }
} 
private void CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument document)
{
    ExcelWorkBook excelworkbook = new ExcelWorkBook();
    ExcelSheetHelper excelworksheet = new ExcelSheetHelper();
    ExcelSharedStringsTable excelsharedtable = new ExcelSharedStringsTable();
    ExcelWorkSheetPartBuilder excelworksheetbuilder = new ExcelWorkSheetPartBuilder();
    ExtendedFilePropertiesPart extendedFilePropertiesPart1 = document.AddNewPart<ExtendedFilePropertiesPart>("rId3");
    ExcelWorkSheetPartBuilder.GenerateExtendedFilePropertiesPart1Content(extendedFilePropertiesPart1);

    WorkbookPart workbookPart1 = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    excelworkbook.GenerateWorkbookPartContent(workbookPart1);


    WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart1 = workbookPart1.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rId5");
    ExcelWorkBook.GenerateWorkbookStylesPart1Content(workbookStylesPart1);

    SetPackageProperties(document);
}

public void GenerateWorkbookPartContent(WorkbookPart workbookPart1)
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", rNameSpace);
    FileVersion fileVersion1 = GenerateFileVersion();
    WorkbookProperties workbookProperties1 = GenerateWorkbookProperties();

    BookViews bookViews1 = GenerateBookViews();

    Sheets sheets1 = GenerateSheets();

    DefinedNames definedNames1 = GenerateDefinedNames();

    CalculationProperties calculationProperties1 = GenerateCalculationProperties();

    CustomWorkbookViews customWorkbookViews1 = GenerateCustomWorkbookViews();


    workbook.Append(fileVersion1);
    workbook.Append(workbookProperties1);
    workbook.Append(bookViews1);
    workbook.Append(sheets1);
    workbook.Append(definedNames1);
    workbook.Append(calculationProperties1);
    workbook.Append(customWorkbookViews1);

    workbookPart1.Workbook = workbook;
}

// Creates an FileVersion instance and adds its children.
public FileVersion GenerateFileVersion()
{
    FileVersion fileVersion1 = new FileVersion() { ApplicationName = "xl", LastEdited = "5", LowestEdited = "5", BuildVersion = "9303" };
    return fileVersion1;
}

// Creates an WorkbookProperties instance and adds its children.
public WorkbookProperties GenerateWorkbookProperties()
{
    WorkbookProperties workbookProperties1 = new WorkbookProperties() { HidePivotFieldList = true };
    return workbookProperties1;
}

// Creates an BookViews instance and adds its children.
public BookViews GenerateBookViews()
{
    BookViews bookViews1 = new BookViews();
    WorkbookView workbookView1 = new WorkbookView() { XWindow = -75, YWindow = 270, WindowWidth = (UInt32Value)15435U, WindowHeight = (UInt32Value)6930U };

    bookViews1.Append(workbookView1);
    return bookViews1;
}

// Creates an Sheets instance and adds its children.
public Sheets GenerateSheets()
{
    Sheets sheets1 = new Sheets();
    Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet() { Name = String.Format("{0}", worksheetname), SheetId = (UInt32Value)8U, Id = "rId1" };

    sheets1.Append(sheet1);
    return sheets1;
}

// Creates an DefinedNames instance and adds its children.
public DefinedNames GenerateDefinedNames()
{
    DefinedNames definedNames1 = new DefinedNames();
    DefinedName definedName1 = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm._FilterDatabase", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName1.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!$A$6:$EO$1269", worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName2 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_32BE30F1_B609_44A0_A38A_666CEFFB64E2_.wvu.Cols", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName2.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!", worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName3 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_32BE30F1_B609_44A0_A38A_666CEFFB64E2_.wvu.FilterData", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName3.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!", worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName4 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_5098B70B_692A_450A_8DAE_5172C296966E_.wvu.FilterData", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName4.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!", worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName5 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_7C00A233_927A_41FE_802C_48F5F9E9D5B6_.wvu.FilterData", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName5.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!",worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName6 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_AC112ED6_0017_40BF_884A_9B7959C37BF0_.wvu.FilterData", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName6.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!", worksheetname);
    DefinedName definedName7 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Z_E444BF53_6DCE_4910_823C_F60AE88C96EE_.wvu.FilterData", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Hidden = true };
    definedName7.Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!#REF!",worksheetname);

    definedNames1.Append(definedName1);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName2);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName3);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName4);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName5);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName6);
    definedNames1.Append(definedName7);
    return definedNames1;
}

// Creates an CalculationProperties instance and adds its children.
public CalculationProperties GenerateCalculationProperties()
{
    CalculationProperties calculationProperties1 = new CalculationProperties() { CalculationId = (UInt32Value)125725U };
    return calculationProperties1;
}

// Creates an CustomWorkbookViews instance and adds its children.
public CustomWorkbookViews GenerateCustomWorkbookViews()
{
    CustomWorkbookViews customWorkbookViews1 = new CustomWorkbookViews();
    CustomWorkbookView customWorkbookView1 = new CustomWorkbookView() { Name = "A - Personal View", Guid = "{5098B70B-692A-450A-8DAE-5172C296966E}", MergeInterval = (UInt32Value)0U, PersonalView = true, Maximized = true, XWindow = 1, YWindow = 1, WindowWidth = (UInt32Value)1366U, WindowHeight = (UInt32Value)494U, ActiveSheetId = (UInt32Value)3U };
    CustomWorkbookView customWorkbookView2 = new CustomWorkbookView() { Name = "B - Personal View", Guid = "{7C00A233-927A-41FE-802C-48F5F9E9D5B6}", MergeInterval = (UInt32Value)0U, PersonalView = true, Maximized = true, XWindow = 1, YWindow = 1, WindowWidth = (UInt32Value)1024U, WindowHeight = (UInt32Value)487U, ActiveSheetId = (UInt32Value)3U };
    CustomWorkbookView customWorkbookView3 = new CustomWorkbookView() { Name = "C - Personal View", Guid = "{32BE30F1-B609-44A0-A38A-666CEFFB64E2}", MergeInterval = (UInt32Value)0U, PersonalView = true, Maximized = true, XWindow = 1, YWindow = 1, WindowWidth = (UInt32Value)1280U, WindowHeight = (UInt32Value)481U, ActiveSheetId = (UInt32Value)3U };

    customWorkbookViews1.Append(customWorkbookView1);
    customWorkbookViews1.Append(customWorkbookView2);
    customWorkbookViews1.Append(customWorkbookView3);
    return customWorkbookViews1;
}

public void ValidateDocument()
{
    try
    {
        OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
        int count = 0;
        IDictionary<String, String> ErrorLog = new Dictionary<String, String>();

        using (StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter("Errolog.txt"))
        {
            foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in validator.Validate(WordprocessingDocument.Open(FilePath, true)))
            {
                count++;
                f.WriteLine("Error " + count);
                f.WriteLine("Description: " + error.Description);
                f.WriteLine("Path: " + error.Path.XPath);
                f.WriteLine("Part: " + error.Part.Uri);
                f.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                f.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                f.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
            }
            f.Flush();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

In my specific case, I was having this problem because of too long Worksheet names. This is what was happening to me:

- On the first run of my program, I was trying to creating Worksheets with really big names.
- Excel automatically cropped the big names to 31 characters. No exception was thrown. That is, I thought I was saving the original big name but I was actually saving the 31 characters long cropped string.
- On the second run of my program, I was checking if this specific Worksheet existed already, but I thought it didn't exist because the existing one was cropped.
- I was saving the Worksheet again. No exception thrown, but then, the new one was also cropped and now the XML contains 2 definitions of the same worksheet.
- This causes Excel to attempt to repair the resulting Spreadsheet. Even though it works properly, I think it was simply throwing away the second one and using the first, which wasn't what I wanted.

I fixed the problem by cropping the 31 characters beforehand, before all the comparisons. Now it works perfectly

Comment: Same happened to me. MS Excel 2010 game an error like: "repaired records: sheet properties: /xl/workbook.xml part". Cropped the sheet's names to 31 characters, then the error was fixed.

Comment: For me too, precisely `worksheetName.slice(0, 31);` helped, no more no less.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question asked long ago, i thought my experience will solve someones problem. So am posting my answer here.

I had a similar problem. It occurs due the no. of characters in a sheet name exceeds the limit 31. Sheet name characters must be <= 31.

It won't throw any exception while creating, but gives error while opening in Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The Open XML SDK does not constrain you to producing a valid document. However, there is the `OpenXmlValidator` class which you can use to report any errors in the generated document. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/09/24/finding-open-xml-errors-with-open-xml-sdk-validation.aspx), which has a good example.

Comment: I am also taking advantage of that but it does not seem to be reporting any errors on the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well, because I was using `0` as my `SheetId`, something like:

```
var sheet1 = new Sheet() { Name = "Test", SheetId = (UInt32Value)0U, Id = "rId1" };
```

Excel starts counting from 1, not 0. This is not only true for row numbers, it applies to sheet numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As Murugesan Said in the above comment, i fixed this error by renaming the file name of my excel document. 
For example: In my case , the name of the document was 'My Sample Export Data Sheet'. I have renamed the file to 'MySampleExportDataSheet' and everything worked well later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the tab name consists single quote, i.e.: "my tab's".
I just omitted them:

```
title = title.replace(/'/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, some of our worksheet names contained square brackets, e.g.:

```
Students [Primary]
Students [Secondary]
```

Replacing square brackets with round brackets fixed it:

```
Students (Primary)
Students (Secondary)
```

(For some reason, our customer didn't want these worksheets called **Primary Students**, **Secondary Students**, hence using brackets)

For us, the error message when opening the workbook in Excel was:

> We found a problem with some content in 'workbook.xlsx'.
> Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?
> If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Clicking Yes then allowed Excel to open the workbook, and it displayed the message

> Repaired Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this. It may also be because your sheet names are not unique. My issue was that, because of the char limit, 3 sheets wound up with the exact same name. When I repaired the file Excel renamed the duplicate sheets.

So if the above answers don't work, repair the file then look for a sheet named Recovered_Sheet1. That will tell you what sheet name has the issue (duplicate in my case).